# Decrypt FTP passwords stored on Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

There is anyway to decrypt the FTP passwords stored on Netbeans (from PHP projects) on folder called "keyring", assuming that I have informations from my windows account ???

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had lost password of one of my ftp sites.
I tried to connect with Wireshark sniffing TCP connections.
and i managed to get back the lost password.

Comment: Might be a good idea even though it's not really what he was looking for

Answer (score -2):

**[WRONG ! See below]** No, passwords are not "encrypted" but "hashed", which is a single-way operation.

---

**EDIT:** This answer is shamefully wrong, and sits here like this since 3 years. I am deeply sorry, I don't even know why I answered something so stupid.

An easy way to get back this password would be try to connect to a server using it and dumping it using Wireshark sniffing the TCP connection.

Comment: Thats not right otherwise the program would not be able to use the stored password to connect with FTP